# PG_Agent doesn't execute query

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

Hi I am trying to run a few querys with PG_Agent in my Postgres Database but it won't work.
If I copy the Statement and run it manually it works just perfect. So there must be an error with pgagent or maybe some permissions.

```
Copy (select * from public."table1") TO 'D:\\Export\\Data\\Archive.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

This is my pgpass file:

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:*password*
```

Does anyone have a solution or had the same problem? I googled for hours and no solution helped me out.
Thanks

Comment: Look at the Postgres log to see what it says.

Comment: There is no entry regarding the job in the logfiles of the Database.

Comment: I suspect the user that pgAgent is running as does not have permissions on `D:\\Export\\Data\\Archive.csv`. I don't know how to verify that though. You might try the mailing list [pgadmin-support](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgadmin-support/),  there should be people there that know more about this.

Comment: I tried it with an insert command but it didn't work either

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you are pointing at the wrong database with the pgAgent commands.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Solution:
I realised that pgagent doesn't work with postgre 15 in my case. I installed version 16 and migrated my database. Now everything works fine.